# Lenovo S10-2 easy camera not detected

Tags: 12.10, skype, webcam, lenovo

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.10 on the Gnome3 desktop environment. My webcam was working fine during the Ubuntu installation when it asked me to be snapped by my webcam or choose a picture instead.

However, the webcam does not show on Skype 4.1.10, which i installed earlier today. The VIDEO DEVICE tab in skype options does not detect a webcam. Neither does Cheese and shows a blank screen.

I don't even know if correct drivers for my cam are installed or not. Gnome3 does not have "hardware" in system settings and I cannot find any way to install additional hardware drivers.

I have a Lenovo S10-2 netbook with the following specs:

```
Intel® Atom™ CPU N280 @ 1.66GHz × 2 
Ram: 993.4 MiB
Graphics: unknown (On board?)
Ubuntu Partition: 14 GB
OS type: 32 bit
```

typing lsusb in the terminal gives me this output:

```
STARTS

Bus 005 Device 002: ID 0a5c:2150 Broadcom Corp. BCM2046 Bluetooth Device
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

ENDS
```

No luck with several thread on ubuntuforums or askubuntu or https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SkypeWebCams

Downloaded this :https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/quantal/+source/libwebcam but again, don't know how to install it or is it even going to help.

I am a journalist and need to use Skype a lot for video interviews. I would be really grateful for any help to get me out of this mess.

Anybody???

Answer (score 1):

Got it: <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>.

Works like a charm.